# Pearson's r and what its value represents and how it varies?

Tags: regression, self-study, correlation, pearson-r

this question was asked in **Basic Statistics** Course on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/basic-statistics/exam/IGjAz/correlation-and-regression) website.

What can you conclude about a Pearson's r that is bigger than 1?

Options:

1. The correlation is very high.
2. This is impossible. Correlations are always between 0 and 1.
3. There is a non-lineair relationship between X and Y.
4. This is impossible. [Correlations are always between -1 and 1](https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/pearson-correlation-coefficient-statistical-guide.php).

Other than `Linear Correlation` what are other types of Correlations? An example would be very helpful for such scenario.

Comment: Whenever you see "correlation" in a probability or statistics context, you can be fairly confident it's referring to Pearson's correlation coefficient (aka Pearson's r).

Comment: @MatthewGunn No it's not. It can be Kendall correlation.

Comment: @Student There are many other measures of correlation as well, but for all of them, unless it's otherwise obvious from context, "correlation" without any other qualifier is conventionally Pearson correlation. So Matthew Gunn is quite right to say "you can be fairly confident" that "correlation" refers to Pearson's r (but not absolutely confident, of course, outside cases like the above where it's explicitly mentioned).

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, Pearson's correlation can't be outside [-1,1].

Relationship is a very general term, everything can have a relationship. For example, two variables can be independent or perfectly correlated. It can also be a sqrt-root non-linear related etc. Your question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Hi I've modified my question and please let me know if it makes sense now.